# Regular Expression Validation in asp.net displaying the error message even when the phone number is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```js
function regex() {
  var regex = new RegExp(/^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
  regex.test('0501234567'); // return true;
  regex.test('0521234567'); // return false; 
}
 regex()
```

```html
<div class="newAcc">
  <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server" CssClass="phone" value="+966" placeholder="+966"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="يرجى كتابة رقم هاتف صحيح" CssClass="errorMassege" ControlToValidate="phone" ForeColor="#CC1007" ValidationExpression="/^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/"
    display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
```

the regex is working correct and the massage error displays even if the phone number is correct, what is the problem with my code? Also i have added a javascript and jQuery file at the head and didn't benefit..what can i do please help me ?

Comment: where can i put the first code ? i put it in the javascript file, and then linked the file into the asp.net file but didn't  work ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The / at the beginning and end of the regular expression is JavaScript specific syntax to tell it that this is a regular expression.

In Asp.NET validator your expression should be `ValidationExpression="^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$"`

Note that I removed the / at the beginning and the end of the expression.